# document.ready and ExecuteOrDelayScriptLoaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a dilemma - my javascript code needs to be executed when the DOM is ready. However, at the same time I need to be able to hook up to the load event of another script. So hypothetically speaking I need something like this:

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getData, "sp.js");


 function getData() {


       (document.ready(function() {

            //my code to get data from sharepoint list.  
       }));

 }
```

Only the latter does not seem to work.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('sp.js', function() {
        //your code to get data from sharepoint list.
    });
});
```

For even more control over script loading, try a script loader like the simple and lightweight yepnope.js or the more complex LABjs.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You'll most likely be loading sp.js twice.

Comment: @hamboy ready event on the document should only run once, and $.getScript() should only load the script once. If either is not working like that, it's browser or jQuery bug respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to do it like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function getData(){
        //your code to get data from sharepoint list.  
    }, "sp.js");
 });
```

Comment: If jQuery isn't available, you can use _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, MooTools, or any other library - there is a standard function you can hook into, which checks if the DOM and your assets are loaded.

For example, in jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/